# Getting values from a text input, and putting it into node express (or jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, express

I am building a site that, based on a user input, will then search Twitter's API. I have it working, if I hardcode what the search is:

app.js (node express)

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var Twit = require('twit')

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         'bla'
  , consumer_secret:      'bla'
  , access_token:         '35929248-bla'
  , access_token_secret:  'bla'
})

//get based on search term, count, location, etc
app.get('/tw', function (req, res) {
    T.get('search/tweets', { q: 'beverly hills playhouse', count: 100}, function(err, data, response) {
    res.send(data);
  });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});
```

And here is my jquery:

```
$(function () {

    $("#search-button").click(function() {
        $.getJSON(
            //URL of web service
            "http://localhost:3000/tw"

        ).done(function (result) {
            console.log(result);

        });
    });
});
```

Now, what I want to change based on user input on my HTML is the q: 'beverly hills playhouse', and count: and I guess every other variable for other get methods that I will use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you send the request to your server as a post request, you can send the information you get from jQuery in the request and then on the server side use the request information you just sent it to send the api call to twitter. Things I would recommend looking into are:

body-parser - https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser ( for parsing incoming requests and converting to nice easy to use json objects )

ajax calls and promises - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ ( for making javascript perform side tasks )

postman - https://www.getpostman.com/ ( a nice way to make api requests )

as with most things in programming, there are many ways do what you want. I haven't tested this code, but I would probably do it like this

app.js:

```
var express     = require('express')
var app         = express()
var Twit        = require('twit')

//Include body-parser for middleware
var boadyParser = require( 'body-parser' )

//This sets bodyParser to act as middleware and go over all requests sent to your server
app.use( bodyParser.json() );

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

var T = new Twit({
    consumer_key:         'bla'
  , consumer_secret:      'bla'
  , access_token:         '35929248-bla'
  , access_token_secret:  'bla'
})

//get based on search term, count, location, etc
app.post('/tw', function (req, res) {
    var search = req.body.search;
    T.get('search/tweets', { q: search, count: 100}, function(err, data, response) {
    res.send(data);
  });
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;
  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);

});
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Enter twitter search terms">

     $("#search-button").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
               url: "http://localhost:3000/tw",
               method: "POST",
               data: $("#search").val()
        })
     });
```